# MQDestination overriding accounting token value

Tags: java, jms, mule, ibm-mq, mq

I am trying to set the Accounting Token on the a message which my system received from inbound queue. I am setting this token using the following.

```
msg.setObjectProperty(JmsConstants.JMS_IBM_MQMD_ACCOUNTINGTOKEN,value)
```

Also I have the following properties in my JmsSUpport class

```
((JmsDestination) dest).setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_READ_ENABLED, true);
((JmsDestination) dest).setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_WRITE_ENABLED, true);    
((MQDestination) dest).setMQMDWriteEnabled(true);
((MQDestination) dest).setMQMDReadEnabled(true);
((MQDestination) dest).setTargetClient(JMSC.MQJMS_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ);
```

Since the outbound queue is MQDestination I have to set the above properties. Now I am observing that I am correctly setting the value on the outbound message. But when the other application reads the message from the MQ it has default value for Accounting Token. Could this be because the MQ is configured in such way to override the value? Or is it because the other application is not reading MQ message correctly? Or should I be using any other property to enable accounting token?

Is it because I am setting ((MQDestination) dest).setTargetClient(JMSC.MQJMS_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ); the msg gets stripped of MQMD Headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, MQMD is never stripped off. You have to set identity context on the destination before sending a message. Otherwise queue manager will ignore the Accounting token. Please see the sample code:

```
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;

import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsDestination;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsConstants;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQDestination;

public class AccountingTokenDemo {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AccountingTokenDemo demo = new AccountingTokenDemo();
        demo.putMessageWithAccountingToken();
    }
       public void putMessageWithAccountingToken() {
            JmsConnectionFactory cf = null;
            Connection connection = null;
            Session session = null;
            Destination reqQ = null;
            MessageProducer producer = null;

            try {               
              // Create a connection factory
              JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
              cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();

              // Set the properties
              cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_BINDINGS);
              cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "QM2");

              // Create JMS objects
              connection = cf.createConnection();
              session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

              // Create a 32 byte accounting toke
              byte [] accountingToken = new byte[32];
              byte b = 'a';
              for(int i=0; i < 32;i++)
                accountingToken[i] = b++;

              // Create destination to send requests
              reqQ = session.createQueue("queue:///REQUESTQ");
              ((MQDestination) reqQ).setTargetClient(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ);              
              ((JmsDestination) reqQ).setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_READ_ENABLED, true);
              ((JmsDestination) reqQ).setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_WRITE_ENABLED, true);    
              ((MQDestination) reqQ).setMQMDMessageContext(WMQConstants.WMQ_MDCTX_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT);

              // Create producer
              producer = session.createProducer(reqQ);

              // Create a request message
              Message requestMessage = session.createTextMessage("Setting Accounting token on message");
              requestMessage.setObjectProperty(JmsConstants.JMS_IBM_MQMD_ACCOUNTINGTOKEN, accountingToken);
              // Send it off
              producer.send(requestMessage);

            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
       }       
}
```

Comment: Cna u please help me out with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424781/difference-between-wmq-mdctx-set-all-contex-and-wmq-mdctx-set-identity-context

Comment: One more question. Is there a way to set accounting token without setting the ((MQDestination) destination).setMQMDMessageContext(WMQConstants.WMQ_MDCTX_SET_ALL_CONTEXT);

Comment: Can u please help me with this question as its very urgent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424781/setting-wmq-mdctx-set-identity-context-impact-the-cod-message