# Setting WMQ_MDCTX_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT impact the COD message

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, mule, ibm-mq, mq

I had asked this question before :[MQDestination overriding accounting token value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259058/mqdestination-overriding-accounting-token-value)

According to the response I was even able to set the MQ Accounting token. But the changes have resulted in an impact on the COD which we used to receive earlier. We set the reply to Q and reply to Q Manager as follows

```
Destination codeDestination = session.createQueue("queue://" + replyToQueueMgr + "/" +replyToQueueName);
logger.info(":::: codeDestination :::"+ codeDestination);
msg.setJMSReplyTo(codeDestination);
```

Using the above we used to get the COD correctly on the sent queue. But after I added the following line to support Accounting Token

```
((MQDestination) destination).setMQMDMessageContext(WMQConstants.WMQ_MDCTX_SET_ALL_CONTEXT);
```

After adding the above line COD does not come. If I comment out the above line COD starts coming again but that would mean accounting Token does not get set. I also tried the following line

```
((MQDestination) destination).setMQMDMessageContext(WMQConstants.WMQ_MDCTX_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT);
```

But even with this I am not getting COD. Its only this context which seems to be causing the issue. Other lines where I am setting MQMDReadEnabled and MQMDWriteEnabled properties is not causing any issue.Can someone please help me on this as I need both COD and Accounting Token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the COD message is ending up in Queue managers dead letter queue(DLQ). Have you defined a DLQ for your queue manager? If it is defined, please check that DLQ.

The reason for COD message ending up in DLQ could be because of insufficient user authority. Please check this link: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IZ76359.

Setting a valid user identifier while sending the message should help. I tried with MQ v8 and I could see COD message being put to a reply queue I specified while sending the message.

```
requestMessage.setStringProperty(JmsConstants.JMS_IBM_MQMD_USERIDENTIFIER, "<valid user id>");
```

Comment: One question here. I observe that when I do not set the Context the value of JMS_IBM_MQMD_USERIDENTIFIER defaults to something but when I set context it goes as blank? Is there a way to get that default value

Comment: I need to figure a way to set MQPMO_ALTERNATE_USER_AUTHORITY somehow